# titleformat not being applied to bibliography

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, titlesec

Here is a MWE of the code I am using for applying a titleformat to my chapters.
But it does not get applied to my bibliography chapter.
Any ideas why?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}
{\hfill \tikz[remember picture] \node[] (nr) {\huge\color{blue!50!black}\textbf{\thechapter}~~};
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \coordinate (leftborder) at ($(nr)-(100,0)$);
    \coordinate (leftborderhigh) at ($(nr.north west)-(100,0)$);
    \coordinate (leftborderlow) at ($(nr.south west)-(100,0)$);
    \coordinate (left) at ($(nr.west)-(1.5,0)$);
    \path[shade, top color=blue!1,bottom color=blue!20] (leftborderhigh) -- ($(nr.north west)+(0,0.5)$) -- (left) -- (leftborder) -- cycle;
    \path[shade, top color=blue!20,bottom color=blue!1] (leftborderlow) -- ($(nr.south west)-(0,0.5)$) -- (left) -- (leftborder) -- cycle;
    \draw[blue!50!black,line width=0.1em,line join=round] (left) -- ($(nr.south west)-(0,0.5)$) -- ($(nr.south east)-(0,0.5)$) -- ($(nr.north east)+(0,0.5)$) -- ($(nr.north west)+(0,0.5)$) -- (left) -- (leftborder);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
{5ex}
{\filleft\LARGE\bf}
[\vspace{0ex}]

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Chapter about XXX}
\chapter{Chapter about YYY}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\bibliography{../references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The bibliography is set as `\chapter*`, not `\chapter`.

Comment: Do you want that the bibliography is numbered?

Answer (score 6):

In case you don't want a numbered bibliography, you need to add separate customization code using `\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}`. Add the following to your preamble (I used `\phantom` to preserve the size of your TikZ decoration):

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}
{\hfill \tikz[remember picture] \node[] (nr) {\huge\color{blue!50!black}\phantom{\textbf{\thechapter}}~~};
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \coordinate (leftborder) at ($(nr)-(100,0)$);
    \coordinate (leftborderhigh) at ($(nr.north west)-(100,0)$);
    \coordinate (leftborderlow) at ($(nr.south west)-(100,0)$);
    \coordinate (left) at ($(nr.west)-(1.5,0)$);
    \path[shade, top color=blue!1,bottom color=blue!20] (leftborderhigh) -- ($(nr.north west)+(0,0.5)$) -- (left) -- (leftborder) -- cycle;
    \path[shade, top color=blue!20,bottom color=blue!1] (leftborderlow) -- ($(nr.south west)-(0,0.5)$) -- (left) -- (leftborder) -- cycle;
    \draw[blue!50!black,line width=0.1em,line join=round] (left) -- ($(nr.south west)-(0,0.5)$) -- ($(nr.south east)-(0,0.5)$) -- ($(nr.north east)+(0,0.5)$) -- ($(nr.north west)+(0,0.5)$) -- (left) -- (leftborder);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
{5ex}
{\filleft\LARGE\bf}
[\vspace{0ex}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, perfect. Now my tikz decoration looks empty but that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @Saki You may also thank me by upvoting and accepting my answer. :-)